# regex add new line after each | in ms word

Tags: regex

I'm a newbie.

I just want to add a new line ( a new paragraph ) after each `|` string in Microsoft Word.

I have:

```
text. text text.|text text text.|text. text text.|text text.text.
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
text. text text.
text text text.
text. text text.
text text.text.
```

Comment: http://regexr.com?35o81

Comment: Not programming related, so better suited for superuser.com

Comment: Also, no need for a regex, is there? What's wrong with a simple search and replace?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Just wanted to tell you, you can use `[su]` for [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the search/replace dialog, search for `|` and replace all with `^p`. No need for a regex.

Comment: very simple solution. It's working. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Why regex ?**

[image]

Use `^p` or `^13` in replace with and `|` in search box

Hit Replace all

Comment: Too much white space.... Crop the image (or freehand)